# How to disable dot button in android Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-studio-3.0, kotlin-android-extensions

I am new to Android Studio - Kotlin, I am building an app with numbers and math operators with decimal point(.dot button)In my math calculator app, if press the dot button, the button should be disabled or not entered for the second time.  I want to disable or stop printing dot button(.) if pressed more than once.

Here is my code

Acitivity.kt file

```
package com.tripbegins.calculator
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import com.tripbegins.calculator.R.id.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

var emptyText = true
fun numberEvents(view: View) {
var checkButton:Boolean = false
    if(emptyText){
        viewResult.setText("")
    }
    emptyText = false

    var button = view as Button
    var isClicked = viewResult.text.toString()
    when (button.id) {
        buttonOne.id -> isClicked += "1"
        buttonTwo.id -> isClicked += "2"
        buttonThree.id -> isClicked += "3"
        dotButton.id-> isClicked+="."
    }

    viewResult.setText(isClicked)
}

var operation ="+"
var oldValues:String? = null
fun mathOperation(view: View){
    var mathButton = view as Button
    var isClicked = viewResult.text.toString()

    when(mathButton.id){
        plusButton.id-> {
            operation = "+"
        }
        minusButton.id->{
            operation="-"
        }
        mulButton.id->{
            operation="*"
        }

    }
    oldValues = viewResult.text.toString()
    emptyText = true
}

fun Calculate(view: View){

    var newValues = viewResult.text.toString()
    var calulateButton:Double? = null
    when(operation){
        "+"-> { calulateButton = oldValues!!.toDouble() + newValues.toDouble() }
        "-"-> { calulateButton = oldValues!!.toDouble() - newValues.toDouble() }
        "*"-> { calulateButton = oldValues!!.toDouble() * newValues.toDouble() }

    }
    viewResult.setText(calulateButton.toString())
    emptyText=true
}
fun clearFunction(view: View){
    viewResult.setText("")
}
}
```

activity.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.tripbegins.calculator.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/viewResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:onClick="numberEvents"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonOne"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewResult" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/plusButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
    android:onClick="mathOperation"
    android:text="+"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/minusButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/minusButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:onClick="mathOperation"
    android:text="-"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/plusButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonTwo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mulButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
    android:onClick="mathOperation"
    android:text="*"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/minusButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/minusButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:onClick="Calculate"
    android:text="Calculate"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/minusButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minusButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
    android:onClick="numberEvents"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonTwo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonTwo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
    android:onClick="numberEvents"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonTwo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dotButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:onClick="numberEvents"
    android:text="."
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/calButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/calButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clearButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:onClick="clearFunction"
    android:text="Clear"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/calButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/calButton" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My expectation of the result

Valid entry -> 3. (.dot button should not be entered for the second time)

Invalid entry -> 3... (currently i can able to enter multiple .dot buttons)

Dot button should not pressed twice. It should be active only once.

Thanks
Mohammed

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for the reply. Can you please help me, how i need to modify my coding to check the button is clicked or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so you want to disable the button that has the name `dotButton` after the user clicks it for the first time :

to disable a button, use:

```
dotButton.isClickable=false
```

if you want the button to become clickable again(like when the user deletes the dot that he already pressed) you can use:

```
dotButton.isClickable=true
```

**Edit**:
modify your activity code like that :

```
when (button.id) {
        buttonOne.id -> isClicked += "1"
        buttonTwo.id -> isClicked += "2"
        buttonThree.id -> isClicked += "3"
        dotButton.id-> {
        isClicked+="."
        dotButton.isClickable=false//**add this line here**

                       }
    }

fun clearFunction(view: View){
    viewResult.setText("")
    dotButton.isClickable=true//**add this line here**
}
```

Comment: plz edit your question and add all the code in your activity to help you  modifying your code

Comment: Added all the code of xml and kotlin files. Please look into

Comment: @user2468312 I edit my answer, check if it's working and tell me if there is an issue

Comment: Thank you for your support its worked fine. I have another query. If i have button , by clicking the button for the first instance i need to enter a value "-" and the second time i need to return a value = "+". How i can do that.

Comment: @user2468312 glad that it works, can you plz explain more ,i don't get what you are trying to implement with the "-" and "+" !!!

Comment: Sure. I need to add new button with +/-. If user clicks the button for the first time the value should return -> "-" (ex => -123), if the user clicks again value "-" should be removed (ex => 123). The functionality is similar as +/- button in the calculator.

Comment: @user2468312 can you plz turn what you want in this comment to a new question so i can post my answer because it involves many lines of code and don't forget to add your activity so no one will downvote your new question

Comment: Created a new question - Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295703/how-to-add-functionality-to-a-butting-in-kotlin-android

Comment: @user2468312 i posted my solution